# insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment when running a load test

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, performance-testing

Please help, im doing a load test using Jmeter and its webdriver sampler. My load test is being cancelled  because of the insufficient memory error that I'm getting from jmeter.

[image]

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: When you googled the error message, what did you find? Which of the suggestions did you try and what was the result? Add what you tried and the results to your question.

Comment: Im sorry about that. Based from my research I need to increase the heap size of my jmeter. So I did that and unfortunately the issue is still existing.

Comment: Please increase the Memory of Jmeter in jmeter.bat file and check. Look for code like this set HEAP=-Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=3036m

Answer (score 0):

There are only couple of thing you can try,

1. Setting the heap size as mentioned by @Acid
2. Use a powerful system with increase heap size.
3. Go to cloud

Now, you are using selenium which is GUI based execution and mainly 3-4 threads will work with it. Moreover, if there is memory intensive task like taking snapshot and saving it then it has huge impact on memory. Try to avoid task which uses huge memory and try if that works in your scenario.

Kindly refer the below link for more info:-

https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%e2%80%9cout-memory%e2%80%9d-failure/

Hope this helps.